# Why does indexing take forever on an Aria table?

Tags: index, mariadb

I have a table using the Aria engine on MariaDB 10.3, it stands at 123.5 GiB in size on an SSD server, with plenty of space available (the disk could fit another copy of the unindexed database + more). The structure of this table is just two columns: column 1 is VARCHAR(32) and column 2 is VARCHAR(128).

I am trying to create an `index` index on column 1. It fulfills stage 1 (copy to tmp table) just fine, and then gets to stage 2, which is repair by sort where it gets to around 70% before stalling and making no further progress. SHOW PROCESSLIST reveals that it has moved onto repair by keycache, which I know is notoriously slow - especially with the large amount of data I am dealing with.

I tried setting `myisam_max_sort_file_size = 140G` in my my.cnf (which should be plentiful), then restarting the mariadb service and then trying to reindex. It stalls once again at ~70%.

What can I do to speed up this indexing process?

Edit #1 with requested info:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
  `colOne` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `colTwo` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1
```

and

```
key_buffer_size     = 128M
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX `indexOnColOne` ON `tableName` (`colOne`);
```

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` output and the `CREATE INDEX ..` you used? And what is the `key_buffer_size` setting?

Comment: But why Aria and not InnoDB?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - Edited my answer with the info. As for Aria over Inno, it's down to personal preference and being crash safe - my data is basically write to it once - and only ever select from it.

Comment: That's a very small key_buffer_size, if you want to use MyISAM/Aria. How much RAM does the server have in total?

Comment: 32gb of ram can be used.

Comment: Try setting the key_buffer_size to 8GB and restart mysql. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimizing-key_buffer_size/

Comment: There may be other settings that need adjustment as well, so I'll not be posting any answer.

Comment: Possibly: `read_buffer_size`, `sort_buffer_size`. Not sure if they make a difference for an index creation.

Comment: Managed to get it upto 80% before it moved onto keycache, I think the key buffer size setting will just need incrementing until the sweetspot is found. Thank you for your help/time :)